# mysql conditional insert

Tags: mysql

can we have sql insert like this?

`INSERT INTO A_has_B (A_id,B_id) VALUES (1,2) IF NOT (SELECT COUNT(A_id) FROM A_has_B WHERE A_id = 1 AND B_id = 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you could certainly do:

```
insert into A_has_B ( A_id, B_id )
select 1, 2
  from A_has_B
 where A_id = 1 and B_id = 2;
```

However, I think what you are looking for is `insert ignore`:

```
insert ignore into A_has_B ( A_id, B_id ) values (1, 2);
```

This way you just ignore if there are duplicate rows and you have a proper primary key on the values.